# How can I transfer a value from a page to another?without changing pages

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to build a website with only 2 pages.

---

Page 1

In this page theres a buttom and everytime the buttom is clicked it increases the value of the label on page 2.

---

Page 2

In this page there is only one label a value that is increased by page one

---

Could someone give me an example

Comment: Ajax - easier with JQuery : https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: AJAX or Browsermessaging. However you need to use js

Comment: Your question is not very clear.You want the user to browse to these two different pages without the browser loading the second page?That would require a single page design and some javascript/AJAX .You just want two different pages and when a value changes both pages to show the updated value. That would just require the value to be saved to the database...

Answer (score 0):

consider the following link as a solution to your problem using **AJAX** and **jQuery**.

http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/simple-ajax-website-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

Go through sessions

In your page one

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['myValue']=10; // here your value.
?>
```

In page two

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['myValue'];
?>
```

Comment: The op wants to increase the value on every click. Your answer has nothing to click on and does not increase sth. To provide an better answer describe what your code does

Comment: Store the  increased value in $_SESSION['myValue'] at page one every time.

Comment: It wasnt a question. It was a hint for you to improve your answer

Answer (score 0):

Js for the button page

```
var counter=0;
function buttonclick(){
counter++;
window.postMessage(counter);
}
```

Js for display:

```
window.onload=function(){
 window.addEventlistener("message", handle,false);
}
function handle(event){
alert(event.data);
}
```

This uses the browsers internal messaging system to transfer the value from one window to another. If you want to transfer it even if page2 is not opened use AJAX to send it to the server and use SESSIONS to store it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
<a href='pageone.php?myValue=12'>click</a>
```

then in any other page, you can access

```
$_GET['myValue'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what resources you have available, you could use `AJAX` to save the value to the database/XML file on PAGE 1.  Then write a script to retrieve the value on PAGE 2.

Alternatively, you could look into saving a SESSION variable on PAGE 1 and retrieve that on PAGE 2.

Session Links:

[PHP SESSION Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sessions.htm)

[PHP Manual - SESSIONS](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php)